# What should I pass to isdigit() in order for it to work properly?

Tags: c

I'm really struggling with isdigit();

I need to test for simple numbers, the relevant part of my code looks like this:

```
printf("Enter a number\n");

scanf("%f", &a);

if (isdigit(a))

  printf("That's a number");
```

doesn't matter what I input, it won't acknowledge it as a number. I saw somewhere an answer to a similar problem, where they said you can only pass the ASCII code to isdigit if you want accurate evaluation (so only 48-57 will work). Instead '2' for example will be interpreted as the 'start of text' I couldn't find any answer on how to get around that though. I don't remember having that problem in cpp.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The function expects an integer that contains an integer code of a character digit. For example isdigit( '9' ).

Comment: you need %c in the scanf and a to be a char type.

Comment: This function if from the family of functions for classification of *characters*.

Comment: `%f` will only read a number. Why do you think you need to call `isdigit()` if it has succeeded?

Comment: You can only check isdigit on characters in a string before you convert the string to a number.  `a` in your code is a number which is the result of the conversion.

Comment: Before then, test the return value from `scanf`. If the entry was not a number, that will tell you. Always check the function's return value (as distinct from the value that was entered). `if(scanf("%f", &a) == 1)`

Comment: @Merna George For starters explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The definition for [`isdigit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) is

```
int isdigit( int ch );
```

> Checks if the given **character** is one of the `10` decimal digits: `0123456789`.
>
> The behavior is undefined if the value of `ch` is not representable as `unsigned char` and is not equal to `EOF`.

Returns:

> Non-zero value if the character is a numeric character, zero otherwise.

**Since you are passing the input to a `float` variable it will not work.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {

    unsigned char c;
    printf(">");
    scanf(" %c", &c);

    if(isdigit(c)){
        printf("Is a digit\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `isdigit((unsigned char)c)` would be safer.

Comment: Good point, added to answer

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `unsigned char c; .. scanf(" %c", &c); ... if(isdigit(c)){` in another alternative.  It avoids a cast.

Answer (score 1):

The `isdigit` function expects a character code and returns true if the character is one of `'0'` - `'9'`.

What you are doing by using the `%f` format specifier is reading in some text which gets interpreted as a floating point and is then parsed to result in the actual value encoded in the system floating point format (probably IEEE754).

You don't want `scanf` to interpret the values for you.  You want to read the text directly.  So declare a `char` array big enough to read your input and use the `%s` format specifier.  This will give you a string.  Then inspect each character in the string with `isdigit`.

Answer (score 1):

`isdigit()` checks if a single character is a digit or not. You're passing something that's not a single character.

It would be helpful to have a complete code snippet so we could e.g.  know the data type of `a`. Since you've passed %f to `scanf()`, presumably it's a float?

If so, the scanf() will return 1 if it is able to parse a float out of whatever input it is given. You can use the return value to determine if the input was valid and not have to even use isdigit().

If you want to use `isdigit()` for some reason, then you should read the input as a string (`scanf("%s", ...something that is a char *...)`) and then iterate over each character, passing it to `isdigit()`